# Bind uitextfield value to viewModel using mvvm

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to bind a `UITextField` to a viewModel, however whatever i do i keep getting `Cannot invoke 'bind' with an argument list of type '(to: EmailViewModel)`. What am i doing wrong?

**SignUpViewModel**

```
class SignUpViewModel {

    let model: SignUpModel
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    let emailFieldViewModel = EmailViewModel()

    init(model :SignUpModel) {
        self.model = model
    }


}
```

**EmailViewModel**

```
struct EmailViewModel : FieldViewModel {

    var value: Variable<String> = Variable("")
    var errorValue: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)

    let title = "Email"
    let errorMessage = "Email is wrong"

    func validate() -> Bool {
        let emailPattern = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9.-]{2,64})+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
        guard validateString(value.value, pattern:emailPattern) else {
            errorValue.value = errorMessage
            return false
        }
        errorValue.value = nil
        return true
    }
}
```

**viewcontroller**

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var emailField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureBinding()

    }

    private func configureBinding() {

        // binding
        self.emailField.rx.text.bind(to: viewModel.emailFieldViewModel)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bind` function expects an object that conforms to the `ObserverType` protocol. Here, `EmailViewModel` does not conform to that type, hence the error.

Writing an extension to make `EmailViewModel` conform to the `ObserverType` protocol would solve the compilation error.

```
extension EmailViewModel: ObserverType {
  func on(_ event: Event<String?>) {
    switch event {
    case .next(let newValue): value.value = newValue ?? ""
    case .error(_), .completed: fatalError("Completion and error are not handled")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This return following`Trailing 'where' clause for extension of non-generic type 'EmailViewModel'`

Comment: Hum, I typed this without trying to compile, maybe get rid of the unnecessary where clause. (see updated answer)

Comment: I've added above extension, but i still seem to get same error.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer (again). `UITextField.rx.text` yields an observable parameterized with an optional `String`. So we need to make the view model be an `ObserverType` of `String?` (as opposed to `String` in the first version of my answer). Another solution could be to map in `configureBinding()` to a non-optional string (`...rx.text.map { $0 ?? "" }.bind(to: viewModel.emailFieldViewModel)`